# Bootstrap CSS Customization Issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just started working with bootstrap today and I ran into a few issues.  I want to edit the size of certain parts of the site but can't get them to change/am worried about the responsivity.  For example in the code below I wanted to change the size of the icons so I added an additional class "size" and set the width to 300px, but the change isn't made on the site.  I even tried using !important without success.  Additionally, I would like to change the height of the jumbotron in the same way but have been unsuccessful.  How would I go about changing these?  Do I need to go into the bootstrap script?  Also when designing a responsive website should I use percentages instead of pixels? Thanks, code is here:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default{
    background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
}
.under {
    border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(66, 134, 244);
}
.size {
    width: 300px!important;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

<!-- Button nav for small screens -->

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
<!-- Brand name -->

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>

<!-- Makes nav not expand on resize -->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

<!-- Menu -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<!-- Dropdown menu -->
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
<!-- Non dropdown -->
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
</nav>
      <div class="jumbotron text-center under">
    <h1>Website Heading</h1>
      <p>Information about the website!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span id="size" class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf size"></span>

            </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass btn-lg"></span>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-lg"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change styles.css to custom.css and put it in folder called css

```
<!-- Custom CSS: You can use this stylesheet to override any Bootstrap styles and/or apply your own styles -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: This is working, thank you!  I set the height of .jumbotron using pixels but on resize it remains the same size.  How do I go about changing the size but keeping the design responsive?

Comment: Is the jumbotron just text? I don't see any jumbotron css in your code

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap the icon span with a h1 tag.
    
    `<h1> <span id="size" class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf size large"> </span></h1>`

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes on your code:

```css
/*
       Put this content into style.css
*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
}

.jumbotron {
  /* jumbotron height */
  height: 400px;
}

.under {
  border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(66, 134, 244);
}

.size {
  /*use font-size instead of width*/
  font-size: 100px !important;
  
  /* this is the last one: 
  width: 300px!important;
  (missing space before !important )
  */
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940712/bootstrap-css-customization-issues 
-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">




</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <!-- Button nav for small screens -->

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
        <!-- Brand name -->

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Makes nav not expand on resize -->

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

        <!-- Menu -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

          <!-- Dropdown menu -->
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Non dropdown -->
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center under">
    <h1>Website Heading</h1>
    <p>Information about the website!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
        <span id="size" class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf size"></span>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass btn-lg"></span>

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-lg"></span>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```